# Count tag repetitions in XML file with Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML file similar to the one below:

```
<rec>
<v001>001</v001> 
<v002>2012609272311</v002>
<v003>616.890231</v003>
<v005>7</v005>
<v006>m</v006>
<v007>^a115001^b1^c1^d20100000^e2^fOvernight^m1</v007>
<v007>^a115002^b2^c1^d20100000^e1^m2</v007>
<v007>^a115003^b3^c1^d20100000^e1^m3</v007>
<v007>^a115004^b4^c1^d20100000^e1^m4</v007>
<v007>^a115005^b5^c1^d20100000^e1^m5</v007>
<v007>^a115006^b6^c1^d20100000^e1^m6</v007>
<v016>ROCHA, Ruth Mylius</v016>
<v018>Enfermagem em Saúde Mental</v018>
</rec>
```

The "rec" tags match there are the registry and I need to count how many times the v007 tag repeats within each rec. I am using the following function:

```
static private int getCount(Node parentNode, String childName) {
int qtdEx = 0;
NodeList nList = parentNode.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = nList.item(i);
    String name = n.getNodeName();
    if (name != null && name.equals(childName)) {
        return qtdEx++;
    }
}
return 0;

}
```

This function only returns me 0, I test it as follows:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rec");

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nList.item(i);
        List<Object> columns = null;                                              
        columns = Arrays.asList(getCount(node, "v007"));
        }
```

if anyone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is due to  `String name = n.getNodeName();` it will assign `v001` to `name`,then when it encountered `v002`,the program will stop and return.

You can change to below:

```
 private static int getCount(Node parentNode, String childName) {
   int qtdEx = 0;
   NodeList nList = parentNode.getChildNodes();
   for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
       Node n = nList.item(i);
       String name = n.getNodeName();
       if("v007".equals(name)){
          qtdEx++;
       }
   }
return qtdEx;

}
```

In fact,if you use **[xPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)** and **[dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/)**,things will be more simple:

```
List list = doc.selectNodes("//rec/v007");
int count = list.size();
```